# In Bash, how to pass a git argument to a function whose body is a git statement

Tags: bash, git

I have this function

```
git_list_bad_commits() {
    git rev-list master..HEAD --oneline -i ${grep:1}
}
```

Sometimes I want to call it just as it is.

Sometimes I want to call it with the addition of the git argument  `--count`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the function arguments to the command:

```
git_list_bad_commits() {
    git rev-list master..HEAD "$@" --oneline -i ${grep:1}
}
```

Comment: By the way, you can even use defaults, `git config alias.gr '!f() { git config --get-regexp "${@-.}"; }; f'` or `git config alias.lgdo '!f() { git log --graph --decorate --oneline "${@---all}"; }; f'`.